# Ajax XML - returns with html tags

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

Hi i have this code this is xml with ajax i want the return value i get from res to not include an html tag because it always returns this value. For example i should return a value of 1 instead the ajax returns this value

```
<html>
</html>
1
```

this is my code for the xml

```
function sendEscalationEmail()
{
    var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null) { alert ("The system cannot process your request.\nPlease use browser that supports AJAX!"); return; }

var params1 = $('#formTrans').serialize();
var params2 = $('#formClient').serialize();

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function generateOutput()
{
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
    {
        var res = xmlHttp.responseText;

        if (res.indexOf('1')<-1) alert('Transaction is saved but there has been an error sending the details to your supervisor\'s email.\nKindly contact the system administrator.');
        else
        {
            alert('Transaction submitted and sent to your supervisor\'s email.');
            document.getElementById('emailpreview').innerHTML = '';
            $("#emailpreview").dialog("close");
        }
    }
};
xmlHttp.open('GET', 'send.esemail.php?'+params1+'&'+params2, true);
xmlHttp.send('');
}
```

here is the code for send.esemail.php

```
$arrTo[] = "xx@xx.com";


$mail = new htmlMimeMail();
$mail->setTextCharset('utf-8');
$mail->setHtmlCharset('utf-8');
$mail->setHeadCharset('utf-8');
$mail->setSMTPParams($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$mail->setHtml($strHTML);
$mail->setFrom("xxxxx");
$mail->setSubject($strSubject);
$mail->setReturnPath('xx@xx,net');
$mail->setBcc("xx@eg.net");
$result = $mail->send($arrTo);

echo $result;
```

how could i remove the  tags from the return the value so i can get rid of using indexOf to find the correct response. $result should be outputting only `1` but it has `<html></html> 1`.

Comment: Are you using any PHP framework by any chance? Or is your script outputting the tags somewhere?

Comment: inspect the request in browser console to see what is actually sent. javascript won't create the tags without code to do it. Sounds like you have other php adding it

Comment: Its server generated tags, must be using some type of framework which automatically inserts these tags if they are missing, or if not by-passed manually.

Comment: I'm using AdoConnection to connect to the database. Does that affect the return value?

Comment: What is `htmlMimeMail`? Are you sure `send` is returning only `1` (or `true` and `false` I assume). What do all the other functions do? Where are you building `$strHTML`?

Comment: oh htmlMimeMail is my php mail class. `send` is returning true. `$strHTML` is the html part of the email im building that on top of `$arrTo` sorry i forgot that info. Also I noticed that my class adds an html part for the emails.

Comment: oh @FelixKling i tried to change my php code removed all other parts and remained this 
`<?php $return = true; echo $return; ?>` it returns the same thing `<html></html>1`

Answer (score 0):

In send.esemail.php
Write 
echo strip_tags($result); 
which should return only 1.